# How to use typescript type in the for in loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a type

```
  interface Test {
  Id?: string
  Activity?: string
}

interface Previous {
  Id?: string
  Name?: string
  Original: Test
}

interface MainProduct {
  Id?: string
  Name?: string
  Original?: Previous
}

    type Product =  MainProduct | Previous

    for (let activity in groupedProductsByActivity as Array<Product>) {


    }
```

But this gives me a compile time error. Can any one help me how do I add this type to the for loop data.

Thanks.

Error is

```
Conversion of type 'Dictionary<(Previous | VIPClusterAssortmentProduct)[]>' to type '(Previous | MainProduct)[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: I hae updated the question please check

Comment: What type is `groupedProductsByActivity`?

Comment: const groupedProductsByActivity: _.Dictionary<Product[]>

Comment: @GaneshKaspate please include the type of `groupedProductsByActivity` in your question.

Comment: Is `_.Dictionary` something you have defined yourself or is it from a library? Please include that too in that case.

Comment: @GaneshKaspate You cannot convert  `_.Dictionary<Product[]>` directly to `Product[]` in the for loop.

You can use something like `_.flatten(Object.values(groupedProductsByActivity))` for that conversion